# Angular 7 router transition conditionally

Tags: angular, animation, router

I'm trying to apply an animation on a div conditionally. I need to slide top or bottom depending on a dedicated variable.
This is my animation function:

```
export function slideTopOrBottom() {
    return trigger('slideTopOrBottom', [
        state('toTop', style({})),
        state('toBottom', style({})),
        transition('toTop => void', [
            query(':enter', [
                style({ transform: 'translateY(100%)' }),
                animate('1s ease-in-out', style({ transform: 'translateY(0%)' }))
            ], { optional: true }),
            query(':leave', [
                style({ transform: 'translateY(0%)' }),
                animate('1s ease-in-out', style({ transform: 'translateY(-100%)' }))
            ], { optional: true })
        ]),
        transition('toBottom => void', [
            query(':enter', [
                style({ transform: 'translateY(-100%)' }),
                animate('1s ease-in-out', style({ transform: 'translateY(0%)' }))
            ], { optional: true }),
            query(':leave', [
                style({ transform: 'translateY(0%)' }),
                animate('1s ease-in-out', style({ transform: 'translateY(100%)' }))
            ], { optional: true })
        ])
    ])
}
```

It works fine if I put in html tag this:

`<div [@slideTopOrBottom]="'toTop'">` or `<div [@slideTopOrBottom]="'toBottom'">`

I want to apply slide to top or to bottom depending on a condition, clicking on a top or bottom button, so i'm trying to do in this way:

```
<div [@slideTopOrBottom]="{value: slideDirection}">
```

and in component:

```
slideDirection: string;

 ngOnInit() {
     this.slideDirection: 'toTop';
}

onBottomClick() {
    this.slideDirection: 'toBottom';
}

onTopClick() {
    this.slideDirection: 'toTop';
}
```

Clicking on bottom button, the new value of `slideDirection` isn't detected and the div slides to top.
Is there a way to fix this problem?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your property assignment isn't correct. Use as below.

```
<div [@slideTopOrBottom]="slideDirection">
```

Stackblitz example - https://stackblitz.com/edit/animated-div-height-cj8ezh?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: @FeliceBiagioTirri Have a look at the stackblitz code sample where Im using a single button in similar fashion to toggle a div

Comment: Thanks @ZamAbdulVahid, I've used your solution to modify my animation function. Now I've a good solution but it's not exactly what I'd want